# Handling a char as a byte in Java, different results

Tags: java, unicode, binary, char, byte

Why the two following results are different?

```
bsh % System.out.println((byte)'\u0080');
-128

bsh % System.out.println("\u0080".getBytes()[0]);
63
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(byte)'\u0080'` just takes the numerical value of the codepoint, which does not fit into a `byte` and thus is subject to a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.3) which drops the bits that don't fit into the byte and, since the highest-order bit is set, yields a negative number.

`"\u0080".getBytes()[0]` transforms the characters to bytes according to your platform default encoding (there is an overloaded `getBytes()` method that allows you to specify the encoding). It looks like your platform default encoding cannot represent codepoint U+0080, and replaces it by "?" (codepoint U+003F, decimal value 63).

Answer (score 3):

Unicode character `U+0080 <control>` can't be represented in your system default encoding and therefore is replaced by `?` (ASCII code 0x3F = 63) when string is encoded into your default encoding by `getBytes()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here the byte array has 2 elements - that's because the representation of unicode chars does not fit in 1 byte.

On my machine the array contains `[-62, -128]`. That's because my default encoding is UTF-8. Never use `getBytes()` without specifying an encoding.

Comment: as far I can see, there is only one element:
`bsh % System.out.println("\u0080".getBytes().length);`
`1`

Comment: @art1go: It depends on your system encoding.

Comment: @art1go as I mentioned (2nd peragraph) it's because you are in the wrong encoding. After you fix the encoding, the results will still differ. for that - see the first paragraph

Comment: My default encoding is UTF-8 too, I agree though that I get a different result if I specify UTF-8, but it doesn't explain which encoding can give -128,63 (I've tried everyone possible)

Comment: @Bozho: The 1st paragraph is something strange - `getBytes()` doesn't return "unicode chars", it returns encoded representation. FOr example, `getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` returns `[-128]`.

Comment: @art1go: Your default encoding is definitely not UTF-8. If you use Windows machine, it's something like Windows-1252, where `U+0080` can't be represented.

Comment: @axtavt - well, that's my point - the encoded representation of the unicode characters can't fit in 1 byte.

Comment: it really is UTF-8 (I haven't got Windows) but I agree encoding "US-ASCII" seems to be used.

Comment: @art1go what does this print: `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());`

Comment: It is MacRoman indeed, it seems to not take the environment variable into account.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a character which a character encoding doesn't support it turns it into '?' which is 63 in ASCII.

try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("\u0080".getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

prints

```
[-62, -128]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to get the same result with the `toString()` call, specify `UTF-16_LE` as the charset encoding:

```
bsh %  System.out.println("\u0080".getBytes("UTF-16LE")[0]); 
-128
```

Java Strings are encoded internally as UTF-16, and since we want the lower byte like for the cast char -> byte, we use little endian here. Big endian works too, if we change the array index:

```
bsh %  System.out.println("\u0080".getBytes("UTF-16BE")[1]);
-128
```